# Error estimates for orthogonal polynomial approximation

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

**tl;dr:** Are there explicit bounds for the approximation error by orthogonal polynomials?

There are various ways to formulate this question more precisely, so want I emphasize up front that this is a reference request question: I am interested in pretty much *any* such results, since I have not found anything useful in the literature. I will note that there is a robust literature on *interpolation* error, however, this is not what I am interested in. There is also a nice literature on greedy approximation, but again, this is more general than what I am seeking.

Here is one way to formulate the problem: Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be a system of orthogonal polynomials in $L^2(I)$ and $f\in L^2(I)$, where $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a (possibly infinite) interval. Write $f=\sum_n a_n\phi_n$ and let $S_N$ denote the $N$-term approximation operator, i.e.
$$
S_Nf := \sum_{n=1}^Na_n\phi_n.
$$
Similarly let $B_N$ denote the *best* $N$-term approximation to $f$ (using $\{\phi_n\}$). I am looking for upper (or lower) bounds on
$$
\Vert S_Nf - f\Vert
\quad\text{or}\quad
\Vert B_Nf - f\Vert.
$$
I would expect such bounds to depend on $N$ and the presumed regularity of $f$.

To emphasize my point on the lack of results, I have not found any results for the following (very) case: $f$ is analytic, $I=[a,b]$, and $\{\phi_n\}$ given by the Hermite polynomials. I feel like I must be looking in the wrong places, as such results must be known!